# C++: How to create and use mysql connection within a class

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm very new in C++.  Where and how will I define the mysql connection in class definition? I'm trying to create connection in a class constructor. And close when destructor called. Just need some tips how to do it properly and how will I call it within class methods? is there something like 'this->mysql'?

```
class Queue {
    public:
    Queue() {  
        MYSQL *mysql = NULL; 
    ...        
        mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
        if(!mysql_real_connect(mysql, getMySqlHost().c_str(),...
  }

void someFunction ( const std::string & MyStr){
    mysql_query(this->mysql,MyStr.c_str());
...
```

and destructor:

```
~Queue() { mysql_close( this->mysql); }
```

im getting `queue.h:231:31: error: ‘class Queue’ has no member named ‘mysql’`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the compilation error is because, as the compiler helpfully informed you "‘class Queue’ has no member named ‘mysql’". One of the rare instances I see a compiler error message using meaningful English.

You declared a local variable in your constructor named "mysql", instead of a class member.

As far as any "tips how to do it properly", the #1 tip with this kind of an approach is to disable the copy constructor, and the assignment operator. Your homework assignment is to Google the keyword "RAII", and based on what you find, figure out the answer why you should do that.

Comment: I need just a sample how to do it. All c++ tutorial videos I watched were about creating 'dogs' and 'cats' classes and there were none similar to this . In RAII samle still quite simple
`class file {
public:
    file( const char* filename ) : m_file_handle(std::fopen(filename, "w+")) `